# blo python tree

Tags: python

Hi have a dictionary word list in bio pythons trie implementation

i have a trie object named t with a huge dictionary loaded into it.

i have a dict map from integers to a alphabet for some odd encryption algorithm

what is the most elegant or pythonic way so when i search the trie, with a N letter word , to omit and delete all results with length less then or greater then N and only store the results with exact N length

say the inputs are 227 and 8733 which are mapped to letters in the dictionary like ([bar,car,carpet][tree,tree's,treed,used]) i only want to keep the outputs as the same length, so when the input is 227 only car and bar will be outputted
the results i want should be ([bar,car],[tree,used])

So i want to OMIT all results that would be produced from the trie that have a larger or shorter length then the original input length

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "omit and store"?  Are you really filtering/grouping the data based on the more / fewer than three character condition?

Comment: @BrianCain Thanks i fixed it up a bit is it more clear now?

Comment: Still no `my_inputs` and indentation is still one level off (and shouldn't be shadowing `input` also)

Comment: Right, although it's still not correct - what you're asking is a mobile phone (perhaps T9) predictive text algorithm?

Comment: it actually does looks like a T9 now i just didn't want to put the mapping i'm going to actually use

Comment: Then it's hardly encryption is it? Why do you need custom encryption that's dependent on the algorithm and not the strength of keys? Thoroughly confused as you're potentially wasting peoples time with trie's etc...*what do you really want*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for word in t.with_prefix(string): # I assume with_prefix() returns a list of words
    if len(word) == len(string):
       words.append(word)
```

Or using genexpr:

```
words.extend(w for w in t.with_prefix(string) if len(w) == len(string))
```

Comment: the first still gives results greater then N , but the second one works great thanks!